# Wouldn't Aether make humans sterile too?

Tags: coppelion

Coppelion are sterile because their immunity to radiation does not extend to their reproductive cells.

Aether is a drug that grants the same immunity to humans.

Wouldn't Aether make humans sterile too?

Answer (score 2):

That doesn't seem right.

Coppelion are sterile because their reproductive cells experience high doses of radiation, not because the rest of their cells are immune to radiation.

It's not Aether itself that causes the sterility - it's the radioactivity. But, in general, Aether is administered to treat short exposures to radiation (if you've suffered a long exposure, you're probably dead), which might not be long enough to cause sterility.

Of course, if a human were to spend a long time exposed to radiation after being treated with Aether, then yes, I imagine they would become sterile.

Comment: Since being exposed to radiation is too commonplace for Coppelion (and is safe to assume that every single one of the operational ones were fully tested/exposed in the lab/school), it was implied in the first statement of my question that it was not the immunity that caused sterility. Your conclusion in the second statement is wrong, then. But excellent analysis of the exposure time, +1. The basic version of Aether really is short-term, but Dr Coppelius won't be a biological dad on his own anymore for sure.

Comment: Since he was besides the neutron emitting girl for quite some time.